# Issue with ubuntu 20.04 and Bluetooth Adapter or rtl_bt_rt18761b_fw.bin?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, bluetooth, radeon

firstly I am sorry if my formatting here is ugly. First time asker and ubuntu novice! I have been having an issue now for over a month with my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04. It was a bit of a struggle to get Bluetooth working with an adapter, but I managed it. Even figured out how to pair my apple airpods to my computer.  Things were going great, and then I can only imagine a system update messed things up. Just a guess though since I hadn't personally done anything that would effect it. Judging by my logs, I may have more than one issue. But right now everything functions properly with the exception of my Bluetooth, which is what I am concerned with fixing first.

Laptop Specs:

HP Envy (Older, 2015ish if I had to guess)

8gb RAM

Processor: AMD A10-5750m apu with radeon(tm) hd graphics x4

Graphics: AMD Oland / AMD Aruba

HDD: 1TB

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit

GNOME Version: 3.36.8

Windowing System: X11

I have spent many hours searching for an answer, and have even put my online studies on hold (not uni, just online self paced stuff), until I can find a solution, since the speakers built into my computer are complete trash. I have searched keywords from my Logs, looked for new updated drivers to support my device. Browsed the support forums. I've gotten close, but haven't been able to find my exact solution.

*From My Log on Important Tab:*

"**System: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: firmware file rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin not found**"

"**system: debugfs: File 'radeon_ring_uvd' in directory '1' already present!**"

These two lines have yielded the best results. But Still haven't led me to find a solution that works for my system.

*From My Logs Hardware Tab:*

"**radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver ring 5 use gpu addre 0x0000000000075a1**8"

"**snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI ATI/AMD: no speaker allocation for ELD**"

"**r8169 0000:02:00.0 eno1: Link is Down**"

"**Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-200:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-200:00, irq=MAC)**"

"**bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin failed with error -2**"

"**usb 4-1: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci-pci**"

I hope this is enough information to start getting to the bottom of this. I wish I was a bit more tech savvy and knew how to better ask what it is I need help with. I also wish that I had links to back to what has helped and what was not helpful.

Any and all advice/help appreciated. Thanks for reading.

[Picture Of Errors On Boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytilL.jpg)

[Screen Shot Of Logs Important Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Iip.png)

[Screen Shot of Logs Hardware Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozgEF.png)

[Screen Shot Of Logs System Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lubqr.png)

EDIT/UPDATE: My computer recognizes whether an adapter is plugged in or not. But will not turn on and search for available devices to connect to.

Comment: Any resolution so far?

Answer (score 2):

With a working internet connection, please do:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware/rtl_bt
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin
```

Reboot.

Comment: Okay, great. Did that executed successfully. Rebooted. Same issue. Bluetooth shows as off my top right display. But when I click to turn on, it says "turn off bluetooth" as if it's on.